# get legend labels (text) from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, legend-properties

I am trying to extract the label text from a ggplot legend object, e.g. for this plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
(p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp, color=as.character(cyl))) + geom_point())
```

[image]

I can extract the legends via

```
library(ggpubr)
legend <- ggpubr::get_legend(p)
```

Next, I would like to get the actual string values that are contained in the legend object, i.e. for this case **"4", "6", "8"**. How can these values be retrieved from the legend object?

*Note: I do not have the original data available, only the legend object.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set up the legend:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp, color=as.character(cyl))) + geom_point()

legendp <- ggpubr::get_legend(p)
```

From `legendp$grobs[[1]]`, we know that the labels are probably stored in grobs 9 to 11:

```
legendp$grobs[[1]]
# TableGrob (7 x 6) "layout": 11 grobs
#     z     cells       name                                grob
# 1   1 (1-7,1-6) background rect[legend.background..rect.19172]
# 2   2 (2-2,2-5)      title             gTree[GRID.gTree.19173]
# 3   3 (4-4,2-2) key-3-1-bg        rect[legend.key..rect.19163]
# 4   4 (4-4,2-2)  key-3-1-1           points[GRID.points.19164]
# 5   5 (5-5,2-2) key-4-1-bg        rect[legend.key..rect.19166]
# 6   6 (5-5,2-2)  key-4-1-1           points[GRID.points.19167]
# 7   7 (6-6,2-2) key-5-1-bg        rect[legend.key..rect.19169]
# 8   8 (6-6,2-2)  key-5-1-1           points[GRID.points.19170]
# 9   9 (4-4,4-4)  label-3-3             gTree[GRID.gTree.19174]
# 10 10 (5-5,4-4)  label-4-3             gTree[GRID.gTree.19175]
# 11 11 (6-6,4-4)  label-5-3             gTree[GRID.gTree.19176]
```

Then we can `unlist` grobs 9 to 11 (with `which(grepl("label", legendp$grobs[[1]]$layout$name))` to dynamically output the target grobs). The labels are stored under a sublist element with a name that starts with "children.guide.label" and ends with "label", therefore we can `grep` that pattern to get our target labels

```r
legendp_grobs9_11 <- unlist(legendp$grobs[[1]]$grobs[which(grepl("label", legendp$grobs[[1]]$layout$name))])

unname(legendp_grobs9_11[grepl("children.guide.label.*text.*label$", names(legendp_grobs9_11))])
# [1] "4" "6" "8"
```

---

Another example to show it works.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

p2 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, price, col = cut)) + geom_point()
p2
```

[image]

```r
legendp2 <- get_legend(p2)
legendp2_grobs13_17 <- unlist(legendp2$grobs[[1]]$grobs[which(grepl("label", legendp2$grobs[[1]]$layout$name))])
unname(legendp2_grobs13_17[grepl("children.guide.label.*text.*label$", names(legendp2_grobs13_17))])
#> [1] "Fair"      "Good"      "Very Good" "Premium"   "Ideal"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>